# react native how to send data from tabscreen (child screen) to navigation container screen (main screen)

Tags: react-native, stack-navigator

in `react-native` i have one screen that contains `bottom navigation` name Dashboard.js

and in that `navigation` i have `'download'` screen that contains list of running download files

i have requirement that need to display that download list count in badge

how to pass that list count from child (download) to parent (Dashboard) but i dont know how to do that

and how to maintain/get notified if in dashboard screen if any new file added or finished in download screen ?

```
 Dashboard.js {

    <NavigationContainer>
          <MainStack.Navigator
            initialRouteName="Tabs"
            screenOptions={{
              headerShown: false,
            }}>
            <MainStack.Screen name="SettingScreen" component={SettingScreen} />
            <MainStack.Screen name="FeedbackScreen" component={FeedbackScreen} />
            <MainStack.Screen name="Tabs" component={MyTabs} />
          </MainStack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
    
    
    function MyTabs() {
        return (
          <Tab.Navigator
            <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeStackScreen} />
            <Tab.Screen name="MyFiles" component={MyFileScreen} />
            <Tab.Screen
              name="Download"
              component={MyDownloadScreen}
              options={{
                tabBarBadge: badge != 0 ? badge : null,
              }}
            />
            <Tab.Screen
              name="Tools"
              component={MyToolScreen}
            />
          </Tab.Navigator>
        );
      }
    
    function MyDownloadScreen() {
        return (
          <DownloadStack.Navigator
            initialRouteName="Download"
            screenOptions={{
              headerShown: false,
            }}>
            <DownloadStack.Screen name="Download" component={DownloadScreen} />
          </DownloadStack.Navigator>
        );
      }

 }
```

Comment: Mainly, you are not passing from child to parent, that is why there's state management either react context. If you will add relevant code of `DownloadScreen` and downloads data template/usage maybe the community will be able to help more concretely

Answer (score 1):

This will be accomplished using props. You will have to re-configure your code in order for this to work (I believe) but I will tell you how.

Screens have a prop called `children` which is essentially the `component` prop, but instead you are able to pass the prop as a component and not as a variable, see below:

Children prop:

```
<Tab.Screen children={() => <MyDownloadScreen />} />
```

Component prop:

```
<Tab.Screen component={<MyDownloadScreen} />
```

Now, how you can pass things up from the `child` component back into your `parent` component is quite simple, simply define the prop you want to change in the `parent` component like so:

```
<Tab.Screen children={() => <MyDownloadScreen someProp={updateState} />}
```

Now, from there inside the `child` component, how you will target that `someProp` is by:

1 - Ensuring you call props in the `child` component:

```
function MyDownloadScreen (props) {
  
}
```

2 - Then targeting that prop like so (Using useEffect as an example, just focus on the `props.someProp` part:

```
function MyDownloadScreen (props) {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    props.someProp(passSomethingHere)
  }, [])
}
```

and then inside that parent component you can set what you just passed up by defining what prop setter you want to set to in the parent component like so:

```
const [someState, setSomeState] = React.useState()    
<Tab.Screen children={() => <MyDownloadScreen someProp={setSomeState} />}
```

That is the way you would go about doing this!

Comment: And how you would get the new files is the same concept, when a new file is added to lets say an array, you would push a notification e.g. an integer to the prop and then set the state in the parent, which will update a badge on the icon etc...